# How to mock @ng-toolkit/universal's WINDOW object in jasmine angular testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-universal

I am writing unit test for a service that injects @ng-toolkit/universal's window object. I want to create a mock object of the same in my unit test.

I am getting an error

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CommonService -> InjectionToken ng-toolkit-window]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CommonService -> InjectionToken ng-toolkit-window]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ng-toolkit-window!
```

My service class constructor:

```
constructor(private windowRef: WindowRefService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
              @Inject(WINDOW) private windowToolKit: Window
    )
```

My unit test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        let windowMock: Window = <any>{ };
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientModule],
            providers: [
                CommonService,
                { provide: Window, useFactory: (() => { return windowMock; }) },
                {provide: windowService, useClass: MockWindowService},
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute },
                { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
            ]
        });
        commonService = TestBed.get(CommonService);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that by just providing an empty object, we can solve it.

```
providers: [
            {provide: WINDOW, useValue: {}}
           ]
```

Comment: It's the same thing I wrote... And no, an empty object is error prone. You need to provide a no-op mock at least.